# Node.js modules vs Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been playing around with node.js, and coming from a Java background, I am struggling to differentiate between modules and the typical concept of objects in JavaScript.

When implementing a modules, I am currently doing it this way:

```
// someModule.js
var privateVariable;
this.sampleFunction = function() {
   // ...
}
```

Now, the way I am using this module in another place is:

```
var moduleName = require('./someModule');

var foo = moduleName.sampleFunction();
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do modular development in node.js - because I realized I am not actually using objects, like using new() - which I would need to do when I want to have collections etc. What is the right way to proceed here if I want a collection of person objects - how will my module and it's definition look like?

Comment: For general background on your question you might find _JavaScript: The Good Parts_ by Douglas Crockford a helpful read. It provides a clear and concise (the whole book is only 176 pages--a rarity) explanation of how JavaScript differs from "classical" (as the author refers to them) languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// someModule.js
var privateVariable;
this.Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
   this.firstName = '...';
}
```

And then:

```
var moduleName = require('./someModule');

var foo = new moduleName.Person('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

A module is a namespace to hold a bunch of related items in. So you might have a "person-collections" module, which contains several types of person collections, such as "lineup", "pile" and "dumpster".

Depending on whether you're using an oo or a functional style of writing, the actual code will look different.